# facing this error , while start of react js app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahmad Hannan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-20T14_28_07_305Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you sure you run the script on the right path? Try to type `cd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm from the error you are printing, you were trying to run `npm` from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>` try moving to your app directory and run it there.

Your app directory will usually contain a file called `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue in 2022 with my VSCode terminal not being in my working directory.

Here's how I fixed it:

**Settings** -> Type: `terminal.integrated.shell.window` ->

Set this to `Command Prompt` rather than `null`:
[image]